# Throttle in JS: Why in console I'm seeing only 1st and last output?

Tags: javascript, lodash, throttling

Seeing only 1st and last output of function call. Why ? And How to see the output of each function calling in a period of 1000ms?

Using lodash throttle.

```
const f = function (a) {
  console.log(a);
};

let f1000 = _.throttle(f, 1000);

f1000(1);
f1000(2);
f1000(3);
f1000(4);
f1000(5);
```

Comment: From the docs: *"Creates a throttled function that only invokes `func` at most once per every `wait` milliseconds."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throttles all the request that come up in the specified interval after invoking the first one (which prints `1`) and Subsequent calls **only** return the result of the last invocation (which prints `5`) **after** the interval is over. So, If you just do something like this, you'll see each of the values getting printed

```
const f = function (a) {
  console.log(a);
};

let f1000 = _.throttle(f, 1000);

setTimeout(()=>f1000(1), 1000)
setTimeout(()=>f1000(2), 2000)
setTimeout(()=>f1000(3), 3000)
setTimeout(()=>f1000(4), 4000)
setTimeout(()=>f1000(5), 5000)
```

Or, if you just reduce the throttle time to 0 milliseconds, it will print all the values.

```
const f = function (a) {
  console.log(a);
};

let f1000 = _.throttle(f, 0); //reduce throttle to 0


f1000(1);
f1000(2);
f1000(3);
f1000(4);
f1000(5);
```

I got this clue when I put a debugger in the function and kept the dev tool open. In that case it was printing each of the numbers (since, there was sufficient delay against each invocation). You can see this for yourself too.

```
const f = function (a) {
   debugger;
   console.log(a);
  };
```

Also, you might like to read the doc: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand that there are two *moments* for a timeout: `leading` and `trailing`. The first one is "the start" of the timeout and the second one is "the end" of the time out.

From the `lodash` docs:

> *Note: If leading and trailing options are true, `func` is invoked on the trailing edge of the timeout only if the throttled function is invoked more than once during the wait timeout.*

By default, they are true as you can see in the implementation [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js). This means that when invoking the same throttled function several times, it will invoke it once *before* the timeout starts and once *after* the timeout ends.

Also, note the following from the docs:

> *Subsequent calls to the throttled function return the result of the last `func` invocation.*

Thus, your code snippet prints the first invocation because you call the throttled function several times and it's the leading edge of the timeout, doesn't invoke anything else because it's throttled, and finally returns the result of the latest invocation.